# Closed subspace of $L^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

The statement I need to prove is following. 
Let $S$ be a closed subspace of Lebesgue space $L^1[0,1].$ Assume that for every $f\in S$ there exists a number $p(f)>1$ such that $f\in L^{p(f)}[0,1].$ Then there exists a number $p>1$ such that $S\subset L^p[0,1].$

As far as I understand, this problem is related to Baire theorem. Hence, I write

$S=\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}( S\cap L^{1+1/n} [0,1])$

and conclude that for some $n$  closure of $S\cap L^{1+1/n} [0,1]$ has nonempty interior. But how can I proceed further to show that it lies in some $L^{1+1/m}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply Baire category theorem to the closed sets 
$$F_n:=\{f\in S,\lVert f\rVert_{L^{1+n^{-1}}}\leqslant n\}$$
(these one are closed by Fatou's lemma).

Comment: Hello, what can we do once we used Baire Category theorem to find that there exists an integer $n_0$ such that $_{n_0}$ is not a nowhere dense set ? Can we just say that a subspace of a normed vector space with non-empty interior has to be the space itself so $F_{n_0} = S$ and $S \subset L^{1+\frac{1}{n_0}}([0,1])$ ?

Comment: @yrual See here for the details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167475/inclusion-of-lp-spaces