# Using Baire Category Theorem to prove $\mathbb{R}^2\not\cong\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, baire-category

How can we prove $\mathbb R ^ 2$ is not homeomorphic to  $\mathbb R ^3$ using Baire Category Theorem?

Here is a standard proof of this fact using algebraic topology. Note that $\mathbb{R}^{3}-\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{2}\times\mathbb{R}$ which has trivial fundamental group, but $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$ which has the fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So it would be interesting to know if Baire Category Theorem can provide another approach.

Comment: I edited the question to add some context. Perhaps it is good enough to reopen it?

Comment: There's a long list of applications of BCT at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165696/your-favourite-application-of-the-baire-category-theorem and this one isn't mentioned, so maybe it's not possible.

Comment: @Prism: please don't do that. It leaves future people unaware what the OP was actually asking. The thing that actually needs clarification, from the OP, is why they believe that there is a solution using the Baire category theorem. That context would more helpful than the algebraic topology argument.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: Dear Carl, I definitely agree that we need clarification from OP. However, I have seen it encouraged elsewhere (meta) that "if you think the question is interesting, you can add some context." Perhaps, the question "What are some other ways to prove $\mathbb{R}^2\not\cong\mathbb{R}^3$" would be more welcoming than asking for specifically BCT solution. Hopefully, OP will tell us the source of this interesting problem.

Comment: @Prism: Form of submission shows respect, or lack thereof. The question prior to your edits looked like vomitted out, hence the closure. This is no longer asker's question, and I don't understand why some users feel compelled to do this. If you'd like the question addressed, re-post in the impeccable way that you formulated it in.

Comment: @Carl Mummert If you believe that Prism should have left the post alone, then why not roll it back?

Comment: I did think about it, but I thought that a comment would be a more gentle way to raise the issue. @user1729

Comment: Every proof that $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ are not homeomorphic uses some sort of algebraic topology.  It  cannot be proved in pure "point-set" topology.  (How's that for a bold assertion?)

Comment: @GEdgar is there a proof for your statement? ("every proof uses some sort of algebraic topology") Maybe there are models of ZF+DC (Hence ZF + Baire) in wich R^2 are indeed homeomorphic to R^3.

Comment: On the contrary, I imagine the usual algebraic topology works quite well in mere ZF.